# Detect cluster node failure Jboss AS 7.1.1-Final

Tags: jboss7.x, infinispan

I have configured 2 node clusers in Jboss AS 7.1.1-Final. I am planning to use sticky sessions. Meanwhile I am also recording number of active online users in Infinispan cache with node IP from where that user session was created for reporting purpose.

I have taken care of scenarios for login/logout where I would clear our cache entries. Problem is if one of the server node goes down, I need to write clean up routine to clear such records of that node from cache too.

One of the option is to write a client and check at specific interval if server is alive otherwise trigger a clean up routine. This approach would work but I am looking for more cleaner approach if I could detect server node failure that gets notified to other live nodes then I could hit cleanup.

From console I know that it shows when server goes down or comes up. But what would be that listerner to listen to such events. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to know when the node leaves within some server module (inside JBoss server) you can use the [ViewChanged listener](http://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/5.1/apidocs/org/infinispan/notifications/Listener.html)

You cannot get this information on clients connected via REST or memcached protocols - with HotRod protocol it is doable but pretty hackish, you'd have to override *TransportFactory.updateServers* (probably just extend *TcpTransportFactory* - see configuration property infinispan.client.hotrod.transport_factory)

Comment: Thanks  I am trying this out to confirm if it meets my requirement.